# How to show that $c_n=\frac{2}{n\pi i}$ for odd $n$? (Fourier series)

Tags: fourier-series, problem-solving

[This 3blue1brown video](https://youtu.be/r6sGWTCMz2k) on Fourier series leaves the viewer with the following exercise:

> $$c_n=\int_0^{0.5}e^{-2\pi int}\,\,\mathrm{d}t\,\,+\int_{0.5}^1-e^{-2\pi int}\,\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}$$
>
> Show that
>
> $$c_n=\frac{2}{n\pi i}\tag{2}$$
>
> for odd $n$ and $c_n=0$ otherwise.

So what I first did is find the antiderivative of $e^{-2\pi int}$ which is

$$\frac{1}{-2\pi in}e^{-2\pi int}$$

Then the sum of the integrals $(1)$ can be written as

$$c_n=\left(\frac{1}{-2\pi in}e^{-\pi in}-\frac{1}{-2\pi in}e^0\right)+\left(-1\cdot\frac{1}{-2\pi in}e^{-2\pi in}+\frac{1}{-2\pi in}e^{-\pi i n}\right)$$

which can be simplified to

$$c_n=\frac{2e^{-\pi in}-1-e^{-2\pi i n}}{-2\pi i n}$$

From there on, I am clueless on how to show that this expression reduces to $(2)$ when $n$ is an odd number or to $0$ if it isn't. So what am I missing here, is my overall approach wrong?

I apologize if this question is trivial or stupid, but as a highschool student, I only have limited knowledge of things such as a Fourier series.

Comment: First notice that $e^{-2\pi i n}=\cos(-2n\pi)+i \sin(-2n\pi)=1$ for all $n$ using euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Then $c_n=\frac{2e^{-\pi in}-2}{-2\pi in}=\frac{1-e^{-\pi in}}{\pi in}$... Now notice that for $n$ even $1-e^{-\pi in}=0$ and for $n$ odd $1-e^{-\pi in}=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not bad for a high school student! Here is Euler's formula:
$$e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$$
Apply this to each of the exponential terms in your numerator. Then think about what are the values of $\sin \pi, \sin 2\pi, \ldots$ and $\cos \pi, \cos 2\pi, \ldots$